# How to know the url which is using in lb-services to call webservice in angularJS

Tags: android, angularjs, web-services, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am new to angularJS. Using lb-services.js i am calling strongloop webservices. When i test my app using browser chrome(localhost). I am able to do all curd operations.

When i try to test using device(samsung tablet), rest service is not calling.

Code:

```
myapp.controller('AuthCtrl', function($scope, $state, $filter, $ionicLoading, $ionicModal, $ionicPopup, $timeout, PhoneService, CameraService, SMSService, UserService, Customers) {

    $scope.registerUser = function() {
       //Register new customer
            Customers.create({
                firstname: firstName,
                lastname: lastName,
                mobile: mobile,
                email: email,
                password: password
            }).$promise;
    };

});
```

Intersting thing here is, when i place my "Customers.create" function outside registerUser , i am able to call my server.

Loopback configuration in angularJS

```
myapp.config(function(LoopBackResourceProvider) {

    // Use a custom auth header instead of the default 'Authorization'
    LoopBackResourceProvider.setAuthHeader('X-Access-Token');

    // Change the URL where to access the LoopBack REST API server
    LoopBackResourceProvider.setUrlBase('http://192.168.1.137:3000/api/');
});
```

Please help me how to know the url which is using by lb-services.js to call loopback webservice.

Thanks

Comment: Your pc and samsung tablet have same network?

Comment: Yes, both are in same network.

Comment: You can call this from other pc or not?

Comment: No. In other pc i am able to access app. But webservice not working.

Comment: do you know how to find the url, which is using in lb-services.js to call webservice model?

Comment: i just made web service in my pc and i ask to my friend to call web service url with my pc's ip so it called

Comment: Thanks for your time. Now my app also working in other pc(in browser). But when i use external device(samsung tablet), service was not calling.

Comment: Thanks friend. Issue fixed. Samsung table was not added in my office sonic wall.